# Testing SQLite Spatial Database (with NHibernate)

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nhibernate, sqlite, geospatial

I am wondering what would be the best way to use [NHibernate.Spatial](http://nhibernatespatial.codeplex.com/) with SQLite for testing purposes?

Mostly, I will need to be able to run NHibernate queries (HQL and others) against in-memory SQLite where Spatial is used.

This leads me to a couple of options:

1. Create a fake dialect for SQLite where it would always return predefined results.
2. Use something like [SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/)
3. Switch to a single database (which is MSSQL2008).

I guess the option 1 should fit my needs.
Option 2 will probably be an overkill and not hassle-free.
Option 3 will be used in Integration tests ONLY, for unit-testing I still want to use SQLite due to the fast and easy setup.

So implementing option 1 (fake SQLite dialect for spatial database) should do the job.

My questions are:

1. Are there any SQLite Spatial Dialects that allow faking the results (always returning empty sets for example)?
2. What other alliteratives can you see?

I would appreciate some advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Fluent NHibernate, you could use conventions to define a different user-type for persisting an IGeometry in SQLite. I've written [a blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorony/archive/2010/05/26/easy-testing-of-nhibernate-spatial-code.aspx) about this solution.